# Centering DatePicker control

Tags: wpf, datepicker, alignment, wpftoolkit

I am using datepicker control from wpf toolkit. I need to center align the content in datepicker control. How can I achieve this?

Tried VerticalContentAlignment="Center". It didn't work.

Answer (score 11):

```
<Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Works for .Net 4's `DatePicker`.

Answer (score 7):

None of the other solutions will work because the vertical alignment of the DatePicker content (text and button) is hard coded in the default WPF style.  i.e. the default WPF DatePicker style has not been written in a manner whereby the vertical alignment (among many other properties) can be overridden.

This should fix it (vertical alignments have been template bounded)
- extract the default DatePicker style
- fix the style to use appropriate template bindings
- apply the new style

```
<Style TargetType="DatePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle.Centred}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="128" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

BetterDatePicker.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle.Centred" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333" />
    <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,0" StartPoint=".5,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#A5FFFFFF" />
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver" />
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed" />
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Background" />
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF" />
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF" />
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF" />
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA" />
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF" />
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF" />
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF" />
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient">
                                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF" />
                                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Width="19">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="23*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Margin="-1"
                                                Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
                                        <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5"
                                                Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius=".5" Margin="0,-1,0,0"
                                                Opacity="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF494949" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                        </Rectangle>
                                        <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0"
                                              Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z"
                                              Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                              Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                 Width="3" />
                                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Opacity="0"
                                                Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0"
                                Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Width="20" Height="20" MinWidth="20" MinHeight="20" />
                        <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" />
                            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="1" Width="19" />
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create ControlTemplate for DatePicker and set "VerticalContentAlignment" property of PART_TextBox element to "Center".

Answer (score 0):

Include this piece of code in the Resources of parent control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of an issue getting the button on the right of the DatePicker aligning properly, but this worked:

```
<my:DatePicker>
    <my:DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        </Style>
    </my:DatePicker.Resources>
</my:DatePicker>
```