# WPF: DatePicker text centered vertically

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, datepicker

I am using a DatePicker in my app defined as such:

```
<DatePicker Width="200"
            Margin="20, 20, 20, 0"
            SelectedDate="{Binding PeriodEndDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Here is how the date picker is displayed:

[image]

How can I get the date (4/22/2015) to center vertically in the textbox (the dotted line around the date is the actual textbox boundary)?

I have tried setting both `VerticalContentAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Center` but this doesn't affect the date centering.

If I dig into the date picker using Snoops I can see an element called `PART_TextBox` within the `DatePicker`.  If I change this `PART_TextBox` `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Center`, the text will be centered (is set to `Stretch` by default).  However, I do not know how to access this subcomponent to change it's `VerticalContentAlignment`

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530640/centering-datepicker-control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530640/centering-datepicker-control) This can be handled by defining a style.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess this is a product of your font size. Try.

```
<DatePicker Width="200"
            FontSize="8"
            Margin="20, 20, 20, 0"
            SelectedDate="{Binding PeriodEndDate, Mode=TwoWay}" >

    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>

</DatePicker>
```